# Does server 302 redirect take "precedence" over other XHR callbacks?

Tags: javascript, http, redirect, browser, xmlhttprequest

My question is - E.g.

- You are making simultaneous 5 XHR calls to the server
- 4 requests are received at the client and are at the request callback queue.
- The 5th request responds with 302.

Does the browser starts processing 302 immediately before processing the previous  4 request callbacks? Or does it wait for 4 callbacks to be processed first and then  redirect?

Please can anybody shed some light?

Answer (score 1):

If they are "simultaneous", the processing order on the client will vary and is not deterministic.

Comment: my question is : does the 302 redirect take precedence over other xhr callback queue?

Comment: What guarantees (do you think) are in place that make the other responses arrive first? Are you asking that if all responses were to arrive at the same time, what would be handled first? I strongly suspect FIFO.